# Apache mod_rewrite rules problems

Tags: mod-rewrite

domain.com/index/
to
domain.com/index.php

domain.com/index/hello
to
domain.com/index.php/hello

The site is use path_info,and the default rule not works:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$      $1.php/$2   [L]
```

I change to: `RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)((/[^/]+)*)/?$ $1.php$2 [L]`

That was strange

domain.com/index/ to domain.com/index.php ***works fine***

domain.com/index/hello to domain.com/index.php/hello ***not work***

and it says **No input file specified.**

Php is run in fast cgi mode in apache

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)?$      $1.php/$2   [L]
```

So the 2nd group is optional.

Also, I would advise you not to use variable passed in the url to match files, it could lead to security issues.

Comment: I change to: RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)((/[^/]+)*)/?$ $1.php$2 [L] 
<br />
http://domain.com/index/ to http://domain.com/index.php works fine
<br />
http://domain.com/index/hello to http://domain.com/index.php/hello not work

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your regex need escape for `/`. Try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)\/(.*)$      $1.php/$2   [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I change to: RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)((/[^/]+)*)/?$ $1.php$2 [L]
```

That was strange

domain.com/index/ to domain.com/index.php works fine

domain.com/index/hello to domain.com/index.php/hello not work

and it says **No input file specified.**

Comment: Try to check the apache's `access_log`. You can find the `.htaccess` translation result there. The error usually because apache didn't pass the `PATH_INFO` to php.

Answer (score 0):

You need to exclude matches that end with `.php`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !.+\.php$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$      $1.php/$2   [L]
```

Otherwise `/index.php/hello` would also be rewritten to `/index.php.php/hello` and that would be rewritten to `/index.php.php.php/hello` and that …

Comment: I did add 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

Comment: @ni: That’s probably the problem: `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` fails and so nothing gets rewritten. Just try my rule.